# How to subset/split a dataframe of multiple columns by common number of values available in R

Tags: r, split, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with over 4000 columns. And columns present stock data and have missing values. The dataframe have various missing values because the dataframe have companies which are listed/trading currently at the stock exchange as well as the companies that had been traded in the past at the stock exchange. If company A has closing prices data for yer 2000 but compnay B might not have any data for year 2000 because company B hadn't been trading/listed in year 2000 hence missing values. This makes my dataframe to be very complex and difficult to run models such as Autoregressive because of the missing data. So, I want to split/subset this dataframe on the basis of the common missing values between them(columns) and then remove the NAs and run the model. I illustrate the data and desired output as follows

```
df
DATE         A      B   C        D      E   F   G   H
31/12/1999  79.5    NA  NA      36.7    3   6   NA  NA
03/01/2000  79.5    NA  NA      36.7    3   6   NA  NA
04/01/2000  79.5    NA  325     36.7    3   6   961 3081.9
05/01/2000  79.5    NA  322.5   38.8    3   6   945 2524.7
06/01/2000  79.5    NA  327.5   20.3    3   6   952 3272.3
07/01/2000  79.5    NA  327.5   15.6    3   6   941 2102.9
10/01/2000  79.5    7   327.5   5.4     3   6   946 2901.5
11/01/2000  79.5    7   327.5   15      3   6   888 9442.5
12/01/2000  79.5    7   331.5   9.3     3   6   870 7865.8
13/01/2000  79.5    7   334     29.1    3   6   853 7742.1
```

I want to have dataframes as follows:

```
d1<-df
DATE         A       D      E   F
31/12/1999  79.5    36.7    3   6
03/01/2000  79.5    36.7    3   6
04/01/2000  79.5    36.7    3   6
05/01/2000  79.5    38.8    3   6
06/01/2000  79.5    20.3    3   6
07/01/2000  79.5    15.6    3   6
10/01/2000  79.5    5.4     3   6
11/01/2000  79.5    15      3   6
12/01/2000  79.5    9.3     3   6
13/01/2000  79.5    29.1    3   6
df2<- df
DATE         C      G   H
31/12/1999  NA      NA  NA
03/01/2000  NA      NA  NA
04/01/2000  325     961 3081.9
05/01/2000  322.5   945 2524.7
06/01/2000  327.5   952 3272.3
07/01/2000  327.5   941 2102.9
10/01/2000  327.5   946 2901.5
11/01/2000  327.5   888 9442.5
12/01/2000  331.5   870 7865.8
13/01/2000  334     853 7742.1

df3 <- df 
DATE    B
31/12/1999  NA
03/01/2000  NA
04/01/2000  NA
05/01/2000  NA
06/01/2000  NA
07/01/2000  NA
10/01/2000  7
11/01/2000  7
12/01/2000  7
13/01/2000  7
```

I would really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: One assumes you initially put this `data.frame` together from other data sources first. Perhaps you should redesign that process vs redesigning this one.

Comment: That said, given your description, it sounds like each column takes the following form `c(rep(NA, n1), <values>, rep(NA, n2))` where `n1` and `n2` can be of any length >= 0. `apply(df, 2, function(j) range(is.na(j)))` should give you the bounds of `n1`,`n2` which should allow you to do subsets intelligently

Comment: I have obtained my dataset from one source but this is the most complex part of my sample that various companies have been listed and delisted during the sample period and I have to account for each and every one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work to what you are doing, and it produces a list of data frames that you can index into one at a time:

```
c <- sapply(df[, 2:ncol(df)], function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))
x <- sapply(unique(c), function(x) which(x == c))
dfList <- list(); for(i in 1:length(x)) {dfList[[i]] <- df[, c(1, as.numeric(x[[i]]) + 1)]}
```

Output is as follows:

```
dfList
[[1]]
         DATE    A    D E F
1  31/12/1999 79.5 36.7 3 6
2  03/01/2000 79.5 36.7 3 6
3  04/01/2000 79.5 36.7 3 6
4  05/01/2000 79.5 38.8 3 6
5  06/01/2000 79.5 20.3 3 6
6  07/01/2000 79.5 15.6 3 6
7  10/01/2000 79.5  5.4 3 6
8  11/01/2000 79.5 15.0 3 6
9  12/01/2000 79.5  9.3 3 6
10 13/01/2000 79.5 29.1 3 6

[[2]]
         DATE  B
1  31/12/1999 NA
2  03/01/2000 NA
3  04/01/2000 NA
4  05/01/2000 NA
5  06/01/2000 NA
6  07/01/2000 NA
7  10/01/2000  7
8  11/01/2000  7
9  12/01/2000  7
10 13/01/2000  7

[[3]]
         DATE     C   G      H
1  31/12/1999    NA  NA     NA
2  03/01/2000    NA  NA     NA
3  04/01/2000 325.0 961 3081.9
4  05/01/2000 322.5 945 2524.7
5  06/01/2000 327.5 952 3272.3
6  07/01/2000 327.5 941 2102.9
7  10/01/2000 327.5 946 2901.5
8  11/01/2000 327.5 888 9442.5
9  12/01/2000 331.5 870 7865.8
10 13/01/2000 334.0 853 7742.1
```

To retrieve only complete cases from each of the data frames in the data frame list above, you can do:

```
dfList <- sapply(dfList, function(x) x[complete.cases(x), ])
```

Resulting output will be the following list of the three data frames in this example:

```
[[1]]
         DATE    A    D E F
1  31/12/1999 79.5 36.7 3 6
2  03/01/2000 79.5 36.7 3 6
3  04/01/2000 79.5 36.7 3 6
4  05/01/2000 79.5 38.8 3 6
5  06/01/2000 79.5 20.3 3 6
6  07/01/2000 79.5 15.6 3 6
7  10/01/2000 79.5  5.4 3 6
8  11/01/2000 79.5 15.0 3 6
9  12/01/2000 79.5  9.3 3 6
10 13/01/2000 79.5 29.1 3 6

[[2]]
         DATE B
7  10/01/2000 7
8  11/01/2000 7
9  12/01/2000 7
10 13/01/2000 7

[[3]]
         DATE     C   G      H
3  04/01/2000 325.0 961 3081.9
4  05/01/2000 322.5 945 2524.7
5  06/01/2000 327.5 952 3272.3
6  07/01/2000 327.5 941 2102.9
7  10/01/2000 327.5 946 2901.5
8  11/01/2000 327.5 888 9442.5
9  12/01/2000 331.5 870 7865.8
10 13/01/2000 334.0 853 7742.1
```

You can access each of these data frames as follows:

```
for (i in 1:lenght(dfList)) {dfList[[i]]}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need them in the form of dataframes,so, that I can run autoregressive model.

Comment: They are data frames....you just need to walk through each element of the list to run your models: for (i in 1:lenght(dfList)) {run your model on dfList[[i]]}

Comment: Kindly can you tell me how can I check how many data frames have been created

Comment: length(dfList) will tell you that.

Comment: Is it possible to remove rows with NA now in these lists.

Comment: Yes. Take a look at complete.cases(). You can use that and subset the individual data frames to remove rows with any NAs.

Comment: I receive error `Error in complete.cases(dfList) : 
  not all arguments have the same length`

Comment: I edited my answer with the working version of complete.cases(). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! once I run this I will accept your answer, I hope you understand!

Comment: I'm still unable to run the autoregressive model on this. But you have provided the right solution to this and extra as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One more solution :)

```
# always give reproducible example
df <- data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:10],
                 B=c(rep(NA, 8), 1:2),
                 C=c(rep(NA, 6), 1:4),
                 D=c(rep(NA, 6), 5:8))

# get indices of NAs in each column
l <- lapply(df, function(i) which(is.na(i)))

# create factors to group columns with identical NA indices
# this is stupid and could be inefficient for data.frames with lots of NA values in columns
f <- factor(sapply(l, paste, collapse=","))

# split initial data.frame on a list of data.frames
list_of_dfs <- lapply(levels(f), function(fl) df[, which(f == fl), drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible instead of list I get dataframes beacause I have to rum autoregressive model on them.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the whole thing into a data.table using the `data.table` package.

Then use the first argument of `data.table[]` to subset your columns and rows.

For instance `dt[!is.na(A) & !is.na(D) & !is.na(E) & !is.na(F), .(A,D,E,F)]` should give you your first table.

Could you be more explicit about the rules to make the various sub tables?

Comment: Thank you. But I have over 4000 companies(columns) in my dataframe. I can't provide name of each componay. NA is the basic rule I need to follow to form dataframes because then I will remove these rows with NAs in the resulting dataframes.

Comment: You don't need to. But do use data.table to do this. This is literally what it was designed for: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf

Comment: Is your objective just to remove ALL NA? If so, why do you have multiple output tables?

Comment: Because it's a sample I can't remove NAS based on dates. I could only remove non trading days.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to make a table where the time period of each trading company is the same? and that there will be a number of tables equal to the number of different groups of trading companies who traded at the same time?

Comment: No that. Actually my sample has companies that are and had been listed at the stock exchange. So, if co. A was listed in 2002, and company B in 2005, so, there would be NAs for Co. B before 2005.

Comment: Check `?na.omit` (there's a faster data.table method).

Answer (score 1):

First calcualte the number of NAs in each column using apply:

```
gr <- apply(df ,2 ,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
gr
DATE    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H 
   0    0    6    2    0    0    0    2    2
```

Now you can subset your data.frame and specify your thresholds which give you 
your desired output.

```
df[, c("DATE",colnames(df)[gr==0]) ]
df[, c("DATE",colnames(df)[gr>0 & gr<=5 ]) ]
df[, c("DATE",colnames(df)[gr>5]) ]
```

Comment: This won't work since there is no threshold. Just columns matching each unique number of NAs need to be separated out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't have a threshold.